# Read specific columns of .txt file with numy genfromtxt

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, genfromtxt

I try to read a .txt file containing 4 columns with names col1, col2, col3 and col4, with data types string, string, float and float.

I just want to read the columns col3 and col4 (for this example).

I used: `table = numpy.genfromtxt(filename, skip_header=1, usecols=(2, 3))`

Then I figured out that the strings in columns col1 and col2 could be phrases (separated by spaces), then `usecols` is taking the wrong columns.

Is it possible to get the last n columns ?

Is it possible to read the columns by using specific column name ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`usecols` parameter accepts sequence of negative numbers.

To get last two columns :

```
table = numpy.genfromtxt(filename, skip_header=1, usecols=(-2, -1))
```

Comment: What if some strings has spaces and others don't ?, that's my problem now :/

Comment: With the default white space delimiter spaces in strings are delimiters.  So you need some other delimiter, e.g. ','.  `genfromtxt` also works with fixed column widths (entered as a delimiter list).